# CSGO - How to display a users inventory from the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, steam, steam-web-api

I'm wanting to make a system that gets a users inventory then displays it as the image and name. I only know how to do the JSON part and I'm unsure as what to do next.

All I have at the moment is:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/json/753/1
```

Is anyone able to help me turn that data into what I am looking for?

Comment: `turn that data` - turn what data? there is no data. post some data

Comment: the current code just brings back lots of JSON, and I'm not sure how to turn that back into text such as an image or a name

Comment: JSON **IS** text - your work is done

Comment: Can you paste how this response JSON look like? You should can get interesting you data using suitable object's key

Answer (score 2):

First off - for CS:GO, at least - the URL you are looking for is:

`http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<PROFILEID>/inventory/json/730/2`

The two numbers at the end of the URL refer to the app ID and context ID, respectively. CS:GO's app ID is 730 and most games use a context ID of 2 for user inventories.

The JSON returned from this request is an object in the following format:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "rgInventory": { ... },
    "rgCurrency": { ... },
    "rgDescriptions": { ... },
    "more": false,
    "more_start": false
}
```

For the use-case you described (getting the item names and icons), you can ignore everything except the `rgDescriptions` object. This object contains an object for each item in the user's inventory. The object keys are the result of concatenating the item's `classid` and `instanceid`, but that doesn't really matter for you - you can just iterate over it like you would for any other object.

The two data points that you're interested in are `market_hash_name`, which is the name of the item, and `icon_url`, which is part of what you need to display the actual image. The full path to the image is `https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/{icon_url}`. For example, [this link](https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposem2LFZf2-r3cC9B-NW1q4OEmePmMqjFqWdY781lxO2Qodih3ALjrhZlam72cIfHdlI7Y1DXq1O2wbvng5646ZrKynpnsyM8pSGKziuLMdo) loads the icon for a G3SG1 | Polar Camo in my inventory.

One thing to note is that the `market_hash_name` includes the wear pattern (e.g., Minimal Wear, Factory New, etc.). If you don't need those, you can just use the `name` from the object.